# How to authenticate Gmail with openssl s_client?

Tags: command-line-interface, gmail, openssl

I use the following commend to access my gmail account in telnet:

> openssl s_client -starttls smtp -crlf
>   -connect smtp.gmail.com:25

then I login and receive an error:

> auth login
>   334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
>   user "some base64"
>   334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
>   pass "some base64"
>   535-5.7.1 Username and Password not accepted.

I'm sure my user name and password are correct. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Can you also try using SWAKS? http://www.jetmore.org/john/code/swaks/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try without the keywords user and pass, for example

```
auth login
334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
bm90bXlyZWFsdXNlcm5hbWU=
334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
bm90bXlyZWFscGFzc3dvcmQ=
235 2.7.0 Accepted
```

Actually, VXNlcm5hbWU6 is Username: and UGFzc3dvcmQ6 is Password:, so no need to define your input.